# How to split a big ui project in C#

Tags: c#

I need to know how to split a big UI project that have more graphic interface (More than 100) in c# to allow to have a small exe file when build solution.

I have develop a C# application and when a need to upload that to my github space, it failed because they are some big file exceed 100Mb.

Thank for help

Comment: 100 forms isn't a lot. There's no justification for a 100MB source code file though. No matter how complex a form is, it *can't* be that big.

Comment: i develop so many app with over 50 pages and hundreds of classes but never exceed 20 mb, i dont know where this 100mb come from, are you using too many images in your from ?

Comment: Could you precise wich kind of files are the biggest ?

Comment: Did you add images to the forms?

Comment: 100mb? are you sure you aren't uploading the compiled binaries and references ?

Comment: when i try to push to git hub, i found that error: remote: error: File smartManage.Desktop/bin/Debug/app.publish/smartManage.Desktop.exe is 103.20 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 M
To https://github.com/josamuna/SmartManage.git

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd there is few image was added in some form and is not big size. For more details, the project is in the github limk below

Comment: Yes, @D.J. is the compiled exe file for UI project that exceed this size, but i need to include all project files

Comment: You could move a bunch of windows and classes to separate projects so they will end up in dll's instead of in the executable. And this will reduce the size of the exe. However, I strongly suggest that you do not add binaries in the repo.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, it was the idea of this post (To split my UI projet to 2 or 3 other project), and the problem is how to do that because there are many same ressources shared between all UI. D.J. also suggest me to not place binary in repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to upload some unnecessary files?

Try using a git ignore file designed for C# and visual studio (or for whatever IDE you are using). Github offers a default git ignore file for VS and C#.

Comment: Did you say that i must ignore the file that exceed this size? Is the output exe file for UI project. I think is a necessary file !!

Comment: @Jo7 just to clarify this for you: compiled binaries are not meant to be uploaded into a git-repository if not neccesairy. the buildoutput and downloaded nuget-packages of .net projects should be ignored. you only push your sourcecode

Comment: Ok @D.J. , so waht precise commande can i use to perform this action

Comment: first you delete all bin/obj-folders from your repository and commit this change, then you select a gitignore from "https://github.com/github/gitignore" depending on your used IDE and rename it to ".gitignore" (must be placed at root of repo), then commit this

Comment: Thanks @D.J., but can i also delete bin directory for Class Library project or for UI project only

Comment: @D.J., I've already do that, but when i modify source code and try to update repository, it not ignore these files (bin/obj-folders) automatically

Comment: https://github.com/josamuna/SmartManage/blob/master/.gitignore.gitignore .... the gitignore has to be named ".gitignore", not ".gitignore.gitignore" ;)